# How to use objects in where clause in Laravel SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.5

Suppose I have some object datas of `doctor_id`

```
{doctor_id: 1} 
{doctor_id: 2}
```

Now I want to find the name of those selected `doctor_id` from `doctors` table.

`doctors` table fields are `id`,`name`,`address`....

**My query is**

```
$doctors_data = Doctor::whereIn('id', $doctor_id)->get();
```

But I got errors from `log` file

> local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031  (SQL: select * from `doctors` where `id` in (?))

What is the query for that. Please help

Comment: Is the object datas, collection?

Comment: @linktoahref...yes ...

Comment: can you show result `dd($doctor_id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an array of the values for a given key using the [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-pluck) method, which you could pass as second argument to the [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-in) method

```
$doctorids = $doctorscollection->pluck('doctor_id');
$doctors_data = Doctor::whereIn('id', $doctorids)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

`whereIn` requires the second argument to be an array.

i.e. in your case, `wherein` should be something like this.

`$doctorsData = Doctor::whereIn('id', [1,2])->get();`

Not sure what kind of object you have got in your `$docter_id`, but the solution to your problem is, you need to convert your object to an array of id before feed it into that `whereIn`.

Hope you got the concept. If still unable to resolve the issue, you can share us your `doctor_id` object, so that we can help convert it into an array.